# Iron:Router + Meteor - Can't both add POST data to database and render route

Tags: javascript, post, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

I'm writing an app with Meteor that needs to take data from POST requests and also render a success page on the same route. This is my current code for the /submit route:

```
Router.route('/submit', function() {
     Records.insert({
        testValue: 'The Value',
        importantVal: this.request.body.email,
        createdAt: new Date()
    });
    this.render('success');
}, {where: 'server'});
```

When I run this code, the data is inserted into the Records database, but it never renders the success template. When I go to the /submit route, it just loads forever and never actually shows anything on the page. When I get rid of the {where: 'server'} it will render the template but not add the data to the database.

How do I get both the data to be added and the template to render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a to POST data to a route it must be run on the server and you cannot render a client-side template from a server route. One way to fix this is to use a `302` redirect to get back into the client side, like this (code is coffeescript):

```
Router.route '/submit', where: 'server'
    .post ->
        Records.insert
            testValue: 'The Value'
            importantVal: @request.body.email
            createdAt: new Date()
        @response.writeHead 302, 'Location': '/success'
        @response.end()

Router.route '/success', name:'success'
```

The `server` route receives the POSTed data and acts on it before redirecting to the `client` route. The name of the `client` route is used to identify the template to be rendered.

Comment: Running this code results in errors because of the way it is structured (not enclosing routes in parentheses...). Trying to refactor this code to work with my current code by changing the render to this.response.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/success'}); this.response.end(); and adding a new route for /success does not seem to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Actually, this seems to have been caused by me forgetting the parentheses at the end of this.response.end(); Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry about the lack of brackets etc, I forgot to mention that the code was in coffeescript, I have fixed this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this outside the `isClient` and `isServer`

```
Router.route('/submit', {    
    template: 'success',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
       Records.insert({
        testValue: 'The Value',
        importantVal: $('[name=email]').val(),//email from input field with name="email"
        createdAt: new Date()
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: This gives me the same error I had before adding {where: 'server'} to my route: Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: `request` has no `body` property.. if the email is input by the user you could first get the email `importantVal: $('[name=email]').val()`

Comment: I'm getting the data from a separate server from the Meteor server and need to get it via POST requests. I can't run jQuery code on the client because the form is on a separate domain.